# Project.json and NuGet on a Xamarin.Forms Project

Tags: json, visual-studio, nuget, xamarin

I am relatively new to Visual Studio (I've spent most of my life on Linux) and I am fairly befuddled about the Windows build process, especially regarding NuGet.

I have a Xamarin PCL solution with several projects (for each implementation), and I removed the packages.config files in each directory and replaced them with Project.json files (although the UWP was already in this format).

However, I can't figure out how to get it all to work together. Strangely, NuGet still works, but it isn't modifying my Project.json files (except for the one on the UWP app). I also don't know what to stick in the "dependencies" and "runtimes" sections, as there is almost no documentation on this anywhere I can find.

Is there any basic information on how the files work with the UI, and where things are stored? This whole method of development is very mystical to me.  I don't know *if* my Project.json files are being used, or by what program, or how, or what would happen if they broke. I don't know where Visual Studio is keeping the NuGet information if it is not in my Project.json file.

I'm also confused by the fact that Project.json seems to be the recommended way of doing things, but Visual Studio doesn't seem to be setup to work with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2015, only certain project types (one relating to Net Core) use project.json.  The others continue to use packages.config.  Net Core is a new effort to port .Net to other platforms, and also break the framework up to be consumed as individual packages, as opposed to installing the full .Net Framework on Windows before using .Net apps.  The format, while having some positive features, was deemed too much of a lift to convert from the existing csproj format.  Instead in VS2017, the features added in project.json are instead being backported into the csproj format.  Project.json is going away or gone.

You can migrate following these instructions: https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/migrating-project-json-to-csproj-visual-studio-2017

You can read more about project.jsons demise in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38537047/347348